# How is a Python Class Object Stored in Memory?

Tags: python, class, object, memory, reference

Can somebody please explain how a Python class object exists in memory?
For example, when I run the following program, how are the newly defined `foo` class and `new_ins` instance stored in the RAM?

```
>>> class foo():
      class_var="blah"
      def __init__(self,x):
          self.x=x
      def get_x(self):
          return self.x
      def print_class_var(self):
          print(class_var)

>>> new_ins=foo(7)
```

From what I understand, a newly created object is an area in RAM where pointers (references) to its attributes (which are essentially other objects) are contained (please correct me if I'm mistaken). Is this also the case for *class* objects? If so, how are the methods defined within the class fit within this hierarchy? What exactly happens under the hood when we access a method through an instance? Please feel free to refer me to other resources.

Comment: classes are *just like any other object*, and methods are just attributes that refer to function objects. This all depends on implementation details, though, is a little broad, IMO

Comment: As an aside, note that `print(class_var)` would throw a NameError

Comment: [Here](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup) is a pretty good overview of *attribute access in general*. For methods, i.e. function objects that exist on the class, you have to understand that functions *are descriptors*, and it is the `__get__` method when called on an instance that does the binding of the instance as the first argument. [Here is a pretty good overview](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that describes descriptors and how you can define your own and how built-in descriptors work, like function objects